# Solving Memory Leaks Allocated via NEW Statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, memory-management

Is there a way to keep track of unreleased memory blocks allocated via *new* statement? The unreleased memory information should be listed on application exit, containig **filename** and **fileline**. This way, it should be possible to quickly identify *new* statements causing memory leaks.

If I am correct, MFC has **DEBUG_NEW** define doing that job. But what about **non MFC** C++ applications?

*Environment used: Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7 64bit.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio CRT has some functions that can help you find memory leaks in debug builds, read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx for more information; there's a lot to take in.

It's also generally considered best practice to try to **always** use the `shared_ptr` class to manage your memory automatically. If you aren't using `shared_ptr`, consider starting.

Comment: Stroustrup said "Please don't thoughtlessly replace pointers with shared_ptrs in an attempt to prevent memory leaks" http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-shared_ptr (best practice is to use the pointers with appropriate ownership semantics, `unique_ptr` is often more suitable)

Comment: I don't really agree with this, but I guess it's personal preference. In any remotely complex project, I think it's almost always better to use a `shared_ptr` over `unique_ptr`. There's a good chance that another developer will come along, want their module to borrow an object from your module for some period of time, and mass replace your `unique_ptr` with `shared_ptr` to make this possible.

Comment: +1 for pointing to the build-in VC++ memory tracking tools.  Always using shared_ptr is bad advice.  Always using RAII, however, is great advice.

Comment: +1 for relevant answer. Hi, and thanks for the answer. Yes, I implemented Visual Studio 2010 native memory leaks tracing by overloading **new** operator. So far so good. I get nice memory leaks report, I am even affraid, that I get reports on places where memory leaks do not realy occur.

Comment: I am marking this answer as the *Accpted Answer* as taking use of of VS2010 memory leak mechanism helped to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of tools that can help you in tracing memory leaks.  All of them have their advantages and disadvantages.

The biggest disadvantage of most of the tools is that they don't show you the leaks in an automatic way.  You explicitly have to dump the state of your memory to file during the lifetime of your application, then dump the state again somewhat later, and then compare the two states.  This is hardly developer-friendly.

Visual Leak Detector is one of the tools that is much better (in my opinion).  It automatically logs all leaks at the end of your application, including the call stack.  Notice that also the Microsoft C Run Time can log leaks, but does this without the call stack.

My personal favorite is to simply do your own memory management.  Implement the global new and delete yourself (watch out: there are quite some variants that you need to implement), and log all non-freed memory at the end of the application (using a global variable that is destructed last may help here).

Comment: +1 for relevant answer. Hi, and thank you for your answer. **Visual Leak Detector** is new tool to me, and it looks interesting. So far, I overloaded new statement and things look pretty well now.